What did the American founding fathers think of contemporary republics?
The story I learned in school (in th US around the turn of the millennium) was that democracy was invented in classical Greece and Rome, was quashed in both cases by rising empires, and then ceased to exist until enlightenment thinkers in Western Europe rediscovered it in old books. They resurrected it in the English, American, and French revolutions, leading to modern democracy.
There are a lot of things that seem questionable about this narrative. For one thing, it doesn’t jibe very well with the fact that many republics already existed nearby in Europe when these revolutions occurred. My sense is that the above narrative was passed down to me ultimately from the Enlightenment thinkers themselves, and in particular my sense is that this is more or less how the American revolutionaries saw things. (Question 0: is that more or less accurate?)
Question: What did the American founding fathers think about contemporary republics in Europe and elsewhere? Did they consciously imitate them? Where they unconsciously influenced by them?
I’m asking less about the republics created in the wake of the French Revolution and more about republics existing at or just before the time of the American revolution.
For example, what did they think of the Dutch republic, or Italian city -republics? Did they see them as models to follow, aristocratic dystopias? If it was something in between, what were their good and bad points?

Worth noting that "democracy" in ancient Greece or Rome (dictatorship of majority, limited to privileged classes) was very different from the kind of democracy established by the US (grounded in universal human rights.)

ACOUP points out that the European republics were aristocratic republics, while the US was a Liberal republic. Beyond that I think the answer would be mired in particulars.

Dutch merchants actively supported the American Revolution but the Dutch Republic was a mess at that point, not likely seen as an example to follow.

To learn history, first unlearn (nearly) all that you have ever been taught about it in school. History as taught in schools was really bad when I was growing up in the '60's, and has only gotten worse since then. For one example: my Grade 5 history teacher was crushed to learn that Temujin - future Genghis Khan - was enslaved as a boy not  due to being some racially oppressed minority, but rather because the family rival who had killed his father, and thereby assumed power as tribal head, was waiting for Temujin to grow tall enough to in turn be killed as a dangerous rival.

@MCW After reading that article, I find it lacks a thorough comparison. He starts with the thesis that liberalism was a new and radical idea, admits that slavery in the US was a failure to realise its principles, and then tries to prove the illiberalism of the European models by pointing out their very same failure to let everyone participate. Why is a ruling class of aristrocrats or merchants fundamentally different from a ruling class of white men, other than quantitatively? The author only touts the horn of of liberalism, but fails to explicitely study their role in European republics.

Hence a comment rather than an answer.  A precise answer to the question would require either a source that outlines the founders discussion of European Republics, or a survey of the formulation of diplomatic relationships with such republics.  In either case, I think that ACOUP's material would enrich such an answer.  But it is a comment, not an answer.

It also addresses OP's subordinate questions; did the founders emulate European republics (clearly no). Did they strive to imitate?(no).The goal was liberalism, not republicanism.

@ccprog - I personally love critiques of Enlightenment Liberalisim that point out how limited their admittedly expanded franchise was. However, we should admit that's our perspective, not that of a contemporary. We should also admit that sometimes quantity has a quality all its own.

@T.E.D. My conclusion is more that, as MCW commented, liberalism and republicanism (and democracy!, as the questions starts with that term) are seperate political concepts. If the question as a whole asks about republicanism, discussing liberalism won't get us far.

Fantastic question. I put in some specific examples.

@PieterGeerkens the notion you should ignore everything you learned at school is frankly disturbing. School history has its defects, but taken as a whole it's better than what's on offer from the modern podcast-propaganda machine. Wouldn't it be better to tell people to be critical about what they learn at school, or anywhere, rather than telling them to forget it? Even outright lies are worth paying attention to, if only because they usually reveal something beyond what the liar intended to convey.

Also, as I myself only learned in the last several years, any notion of "democracy" (or any other progressive tendencies) in ancient Greece (or Rome) was all built up on a huge use of slavery for agriculture and mining. Oh, and women had no place. Plato did not have a job, he had slaves.

What they did (and many of their writings/letters prove it) is watch, think, analyze, compare what they saw elsewhere, what they thought, and what they wanted to achieve. Kicking an open door, but they were smart enough people with deep thinking, so they were influenced, be it to make things happen, copy good things or avoid mistakes commited by others (just to create their own, sometimes :))
